# Switching PyCharm project between Python versions

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a project in pycharm which I am currently running in python 3.9
However, I want to compare how would it behave under python 3.11

I have tried File-Settings-Python Interpreter - Add Interpreter- Add Local Interpreter and tried adding 3.11 from there but it says "Environment location directory is not empty" and prevents me from doing this.

How can I make my project run under python 3.11?

Comment: What for sure works is copying everything except the venv folder to a new location and creating a new project (venv) with python 3.11

Comment: Is there no alternative to doing that? I was trying to avoid that at any cost.

Comment: I don't know. My project didn't like it when I tried, I think it just overwrote the existing venv.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:

- File->Settings->Python Interpreter->Add Interpreter->Add Local Interpreter->System Interpreter (left sidebar)->[version you want]

[image: screencap of PyCharm menu for selecting project Python version]

After you do this, however, you'll be working with the installed Python on your computer, rather than in a virtual environment unique to your project. If you just want to see how it behaves, this might be good enough because you can switch back to the venv you started with.

But if you need to work in a virtual environment, still do the above, and add the following two steps:

- Close PyCharm, navigate to that project's venv folder and wipe it (probably move the contents somewhere safe)
- Start up PyCharm again, then File->Settings->Python Interpreter->Add Interpreter->Add Local Interpreter->Virtualenv Environment->[choose the Python version you want to add]

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it correctly. Make sure you have Python 3.11 installed (it runs outside PyCharm). You need to use PyCharm to pick the existing `python` command from your hard disk. Make sure you are adding an existing interpreter and use the... button to choose it from your disk.

[image]

Comment: But it says "Environment location directory is not empty" and prevents me from pressing OK.

Comment: Are you adding a new or existing interpreter?

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: This answer doesn't address the error message which appears when you follow these instructions